# Can android 2.3 be located through android device manager?

Tags: samsung, gps, android-device-manager

I'm willing to buy a Galaxy Y Duos just to track my car and I'd want to know if its android 2.3 supports being tracked by the android device manager on my PC? I just need to set up a google account, turn GPS and WiFi on, and then go to PC and track it?

Will it work?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll also need to be able to install the app on the device, which requires working Google Play Services.

Comment: I dunno about this, but why Android 2.3 ? Update to 4.x atleast, because most of the app's functionality works best on Android 4.x, as far as I know. 
BTW, that is a waste of a phone's functionality.